# Enable dark mode in ElementPlus with CDN

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, element-ui, element-plus

How do i set the theme to dark when using ElementUI + Vue with CDNs?
I know that with npm you edit some scss files but i dont use npm.

````
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
    <!-- import CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/element-plus/dist/index.css">
    <!-- import JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/element-plus"></script>
    <title>Element Plus demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <el-button>{{ message }}</el-button>
    </div>
    <script>
      const App = {
        data() {
          return {
            message: "Hello Element Plus",
          };
        },
      };
      const app = Vue.createApp(App);
      app.use(ElementPlus);
      app.mount("#app");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply add the class `dark` to the `html` tag.

This is also documented here: https://element-plus.org/en-US/guide/dark-mode.html#how-to-enable-it

```html
<html class="dark">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
    <!-- import CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/element-plus/theme-chalk/index.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/element-plus/theme-chalk/dark/css-vars.css">
    <!-- import JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/element-plus"></script>
    <title>Element Plus demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <el-button>{{ message }}</el-button>
    </div>
    <script>
      const App = {
        data() {
          return {
            message: "Hello Element Plus",
          };
        },
      };
      const app = Vue.createApp(App);
      app.use(ElementPlus);
      app.mount("#app");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```